# How do you find the distribution of this sum?

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $X\sim \text{Normal}(\mu=0, \sigma^2), Y\sim \text{Unif}(0,\pi)$, and $X \perp Y$, how do you find the distribution of $Z=X+a\cdot cos(Y)$ for some $a > 0$ ?

I've found the distribution function of $a\cdot cos(Y)$ to be: $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{a\sqrt{1-(\frac{y}{a})^2}}$, but past this my usual integration methods for finding $f_Z(z)$ become very ugly.

My book says it simplifies to $\frac{1}{\pi\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-(z-a\cdot cos(w))^2/(2\sigma^2)}dw$

Comment: A cursory check with Wolfram Alpha shows that it doesn't know how to do the required type of integral. I haven't looked at it in any more detail than that, but my guess is that you're not going to find an explicit formula for the density.

Comment: My book says it's $\frac{1}{\pi\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-(z-a\cdot cos(w))^2/(2\sigma^2)}dw$

Comment: Well, yeah, that's not closed form. I haven't checked the details, but that answer looks fine. It's really just rewriting the (convolution) integral defining the density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the special case $g:y\mapsto\pi^{-1}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant y\leqslant \pi}$, $h=a\cos$, and $f$ some normal density, of the following general result.

Assume that $X$ has density $f$, that $Y$ has density $g$ and that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Let $h$ be some measurable function, and $Z=X+h(Y)$. Then the density $f_Z$ of $Z$ is such that
$$
f_Z(z)=\int_\mathbb Rf(z-h(y))g(y)\,\mathrm dy.
$$

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I kept trying to do the convolution by putting the displacement in the harder function, and then reducing the big ugly integral.

Comment: I understand. Well, fortunately, the other way works...